# How to use if else elif to create a new column and assign values to it by condition?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I need to add a new column to a DataFrame where I need to add values by condition. There are only three values in the `df['name']` column: **'Enable', 'Disable', NaN**. I try to use -> `if else`, how to change below line of code to use `if elif else` where:

`if df['name'] == 'Enable'` then `df['status'] = 1`, `if df['name'] == 'Disable'` then `df['status'] = 0`, `if df['name'] == NaN` then `df['status'] = 2`

How to change this part of the code for three values, thanks?

```
df['status'] = [0 if i == 'Disable' else 1 for i in df['name']]
```

this case -> [Pandas conditional creation of a series/dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column) not resolve my problem and this is not show how to use if elif else, this case has only two different values.

Comment: Check `np.select`, for test missing values use `mask = df['name'].isna()`

Comment: @jezrael, hi, it's not good way for me. For example, instead of Nan there will be a string value like 'empty'. I need to resolve this use if elif else if it is possible

Comment: Do you check `np.select` ? If empty string use `mask = df['name'] == 'empty'`

Comment: I fix it like this ->  df['status'] = np.nan;  df['status'] = df['status'].mask(df['name'] == 'Enabled', 1).mask(df['name'] == 'Disabled', 0).mask(df['name'].isna(), 2)